# Can this parabolic equation be reduced to describe a periodic waveform

Tags: conic-sections, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I need help in understanding if this formula that defines a Parabolic curve within a circle can also be reduced to describe a Periodic waveform in any way when used with a Fourier Transform.  Is there any possible relation between the two?

n = integer number between 1 and 3 describing the number of parabola within a circle.

k = points on the parabola curve

$$
    r(\frac{n}{2}+1) [ cos(θ)cos((\frac{n}{2}+1)φ) + sin(θ)sin((\frac{n}{2}+1)φ) ] = k
$$

Comment: Hint : term within bracket is $cos\left(\theta-\left({\dfrac{n}{2}}+1\right)\phi \right)$

Comment: Thanks @veereshpandey, I appreciate you taking a look but I might need a little more help than that as this is way above my expertise.   Are you able to expand on your hint and guide to the answer?   This is not a homework question so getting the full answer wouldn't be cheating :-)